# Multi-GPU training error(OOM) on keras (sufficient memory, may be configuration problem)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, out-of-memory, multi-gpu

***I am using keras to train my model on ImageNet2012. When I use a batch size of 256 on a single GPU, it can train normally. 
When I use 6 GPUs, I set the batch size to 1024, I am facing out of memory issues:***

**My environment:**

keras-2.2.4
tensorflow-gpu-1.14.0
python-3.6.8
CUDA-10.1

**Code:**

Reference from >https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set

```
import os, sys, argparse
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multi_gpu import ParallelModel

import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, LearningRateScheduler, TerminateOnNaN
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

from yolo3.models.yolo3_nano import NanoNet

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3,4,5"

def get_model(model_type):
   if model_type == 'nanonet':
        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            model = NanoNet(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights=None)
   else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported model type')
   return model

def main(args):
    log_dir = args.log_dir#'logs/'
    # prepare model
    model = get_model("nanonet")    
    # support multi-gpu training
    paralleled_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=6)

    if args.weights_path:
        paralleled_model.load_weights(args.weights_path)

    # callbacks for training process
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(args.model_save_dir + 'ep{epoch:03d}-val_loss{val_loss:.3f}-val_acc{val_acc:.3f}-val_top_k_categorical_accuracy{val_top_k_categorical_accuracy:.3f}.h5',
        monitor='val_acc',
        mode='max',
        verbose=1,
        save_weights_only=False,
        save_best_only=True,
        period=1)
    logging = TensorBoard(log_dir=args.model_save_dir, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_grads=False, write_images=False, update_freq='batch')
    terminate_on_nan = TerminateOnNaN()
    learn_rates = [0.05, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0005, 0.0001]
    lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: learn_rates[epoch // 30])

    # data generator
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess,
                                       zoom_range=0.25,
                                       #shear_range=0.2,
                                       #channel_shift_range=0.1,
                                       #rotation_range=0.1,
                                       width_shift_range=0.05,
                                       height_shift_range=0.05,
                                       horizontal_flip=True)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            args.train_data_path,
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=1204)

    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            args.val_data_path,
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=1024)

    # get optimizer
    optimizer = get_optimizer(args.optim_type, args.learning_rate)

    # start training
    paralleled_model.compile(
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy', 'top_k_categorical_accuracy'],
              loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    paralleled_model.summary()
    print('Train on {} samples, val on {} samples, with batch size {}.'.format(train_generator.samples, test_generator.samples, args.batch_size))
    paralleled_model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // args.batch_size,
            epochs=args.total_epoch,
            workers=cpu_count()-1,  #Try to parallized feeding image data but leave one cpu core idle
            initial_epoch=args.init_epoch,
            use_multiprocessing=True,
            validation_data=test_generator,
            validation_steps=test_generator.samples // args.batch_size,
            callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, lr_scheduler, terminate_on_nan])

    # Finally store model
    model.save(log_dir + 'trained_final.h5')
```

**Error:**

```
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936131: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 8 Chunks of size 152785920 totalling 1.14GiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936139: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 156898816 totalling 149.63MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936147: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 166076416 totalling 158.38MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936153: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 15 Chunks of size 204718080 totalling 2.86GiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936160: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 5 Chunks of size 209534976 totalling 999.14MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936168: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 239148800 totalling 228.07MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936177: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 245235712 totalling 233.88MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936186: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 259511808 totalling 247.49MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936192: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 3 Chunks of size 305571840 totalling 874.25MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936201: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 316582656 totalling 301.92MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936207: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 19 Chunks of size 409436160 totalling 7.24GiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936216: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 2 Chunks of size 416780288 totalling 794.95MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936222: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 6 Chunks of size 419069952 totalling 2.34GiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:812] 1 Chunks of size 426586880 totalling 406.82MiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936239: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:816] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 28.46GiB
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936245: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:818] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 30652445440 memory_limit_: 30652445491 available bytes: 51 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 34359738368
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:824] Stats: 
Limit:                 30652445491
InUse:                 30563432960
MaxInUse:              30652445440
NumAllocs:                    5911
MaxAllocSize:            616562688

2019-11-22 05:06:34.936554: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:319] ****************************************************************************************************
2019-11-22 05:06:34.936604: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at constant_op.cc:172 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[170,12,224,224] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Epoch 1/150
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 211, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "yolo3/models/backbones/imagenet_training/train_imagenet.py", line 168, in main
    callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, lr_scheduler, terminate_on_nan])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1272, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 265, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 997, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3343, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1459, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[170,56,56,70] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node training/SGD/gradients/gradients/zeros_2558-0-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[170,56,56,70] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node training/SGD/gradients/gradients/zeros_2558-0-0-TransposeNCHWToNHWC-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[replica_1/nano_net/pep_block_12_preproject_BN/cond/Merge_2/_21339]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
5 derived errors ignored.
```

Comment: Can you keep your batch size to something that can be divided by 6 evenly ? Ppost your output after that.

Comment: It doesn't work, Thanks

Comment: Since I use TF 2.0.0 i am not entirely sure about the issue. But I faced the same problem recently and figured out that 'paralleled_model' wont do the intendet job. 'paralleled_model' will produce replica of the same model on each device and merge the results in the end. what you might look into is this site [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is what is going on, but batch sizes are often specified **per gpu**. So in that case you would be trying to put that many examples on each GPU, which would obviously OOM.